# Trying to do an operation N times

Tags: python-3.4

so i'm very very newbie on ipython-notebook. And i'm trying to make a code to, for example:

```
y=10  
y=y**2  
y=y**2
```

and so on. Can you help me?

Comment: What is "and so on"?

Comment: I just want to note that this is not specific to IPython or the Notebook (I'll remove the IPython/Notebook tags). Nor Python either, but in other languages the syntax may differ (so I'll leave the Python tag). Happy introduction to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
y = 10
N = 5
for _ in range(N):
    y = y ** 2

print (y)
```

Comment: I suppose the question was more general but in case of exponent you can "just" do `y ** (2*N)`. Also the use of `_` as a throwaway variable might need a comment when real newbie ask questions.

Comment: @Matt thanks! But if I do that i think i don't get the same results, at least i think! and thanks for the `_`explanation!

Comment: Rhaaa typo, sorry ! `y ** (2**N)` (power also in the parens). Should give you the same result.